# Edit makefile in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I recently created a new project from existing source root in eclipse. I already had makefile for those files but eclipse is creating its own makefile. In the auto generated makefile in eclipse I can see it included all the files in the source root and the the top of the file I see that this the comment "automatically generated file. please do not edit". But I need to edit this file - I want it to call to the original makefile. what is the most elegant way to do this ? Must I edit the auto-generate file (and ignore the above comment) ?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

Try "new project" -> "makefile project with existing code"

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the auto-generated Makefile.  Had to do this just other day myself when converting a project from MPLAB 8 to MPLAB X.  It did not convert the existing Makefile so I had to modify the auto-generated.